# How do I extract all values from a sequenced parser in JParsec?

Tags: java, jparsec

I have a JParsec parser that consists of a few "smaller" parsers, and I would like to extract the total value parsed with those parsers. Let's say:

```java
//                          V-- because of sequence()
private static final Parser<Object> definitionParser = sequence(
        substitute, separator, digits4, separator, digits2, separator, description.optional()
);
```

Some of the parsers above are dummy and are used to delimit data fields. The dummy parsers are `substitute` and `separator`, and I'm not going to extract anything from them. However, the rest of the parsers makes the interest to me:

```java
private static final Parser<Short> digits4 = ...; // 4 hex digits, just a short value
private static final Parser<Byte> digits2 = ...; // 2 hex digits, just a byte value
private static final Parser<String> description = ...; // arbitrary string
```

However, `map`ping the `substituteDefinition` parser requires a `Map<Object, Definition>` interface implementation propagating the result of the very last sequenced parser `description.optional()` to the `Map` implementation, and the incoming argument is a `String`:

```java
private static final Parser<Definition> definitionParser = sequence(
        substitute, separator, digits4, separator, digits2, separator, description.optional()
).map(new Map<Object, Definition>() {
    @Override
    public Definition map(final Object o) {
        ... o is a String here because description.optional() is the last one
    }
});
```

Obviously, I can only extract `description.optional()` value here, but I can't find a way to reach the `digits4` and `digits2` parsers results. I'm wondering: is it possible to extract `digits4`, `digits2` and `description` values into a single `Definition` object using the approach above? I was thinking of a `Definition` builder implementation and passing it through the parsers chain *somehow* too. Or should it be rethought, and if so, then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the return values of some or all of your parsers, then `sequence(Parser<?> ... parsers)` is not the combinator you should use. Depending on the number of parsers you want to combine, you can use one of:

- The overriden `sequence()` combinators from 2 to 5 parsers, to which you can apply the appropriate `map()`,
- The `list()` combinator which returns your parsers' results in a `List<Object>`,
- The `array()` combinator which returns an `Object[]`
- The `tuple()` combinators which return from 2 to 5-tuples.

For separator tokens, you could benefit from using `Parser.sepBy()` or `Parser.followedBy()`: This would allow you to have a shorter `sequence()` with only relevant results.

Comment: It's working like a charm! Thank you very much! Just another question please: is it possible to filter away the `<Void>` parsers? Why I'm asking: I'm extracting the effective values like `l.get(2)`,  `l.get(4)`, and `l.get(6)`, and it does not look very natural to me. I mean, would it possible to combine the parsers respecting the separators in order to extract the values with `l.get(0)`,  `l.get(1)`, and `l.get(2)` respectively? I'm currently using the `list()` combinator.

Comment: As suggested in the last paragraph of my answer, you could do `substitute.followedBy(separator)` instead of having both parsers in a sequence. The return value of the parser inside `followedBy` is ignored.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, `sequence` *is* the combinator to use. The last parameter of sequence can be a lambda where you will get all the results from the parsers you specified before.

So you get `Parsers.sequence(parserA, parserB, parserC, (a, b, c) -> make_the_parser_result_using_a_b_c);`